# Hook into Spree routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, spree

I am doing a Favorites functionality in my app built on top of Spree. I want to write my very own controller/action to serve adding a product to favorites. What I want have is the following url:

```
/product/:product_permalink/favorite
```

...to mark the product as favorite for currently logged in user.

Currently I do the following:

```
match 'favorites' => 'favorites#index'
match 'products/:id/favorite'   => 'favorites#create',  as: 'favorites'
match 'products/:id/unfavorite' => 'favorites#destroy', as: 'unfavorite'
```

Yet the true way of doing this would be hooking into Spree `products` resources route, adding proper members. But is it even possible?

Comment: Quick question in order to, possibly, answer your question: Are you on Spree 1.x? or an older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could do

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  #Add your custom logic here
end
```

Then do the same in your controller and views to plug your functionality directly into the products model and controller.

you can check out the documentation over at http://guides.spreecommerce.com/logic_customization.html

It's very useful :)

Thanks

Ash